# imagesetpixel not working properly - gd lib broken?

Tags: php, gd

I am having very strange issue with imagegd lib.

Please condifer following method:

```
public function getMatrixImage() {
    // 90 x 40 test
    $img        = imagecreate($this->last_used_matrix_x, $this->last_used_matrix_y);
    $background = imagecolorallocate($img, 200, 200, 200);
    imagefill($img, $background, 0, 0);

    echo "<pre>";

    for ($y = 0; $y < $this->last_used_matrix_y; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $this->last_used_matrix_x; $x++) {
            $pixel = $this->matrix[$y][$x];

            // Debug 1 - comment/uncomment
            // echo $pixel ? "#" : "-";
            if (!$pixel) {
                continue;
            }

            $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

            if ($this->id == 1) {
                // Debug 2 - comment/uncomment
                echo " ({$x}.{$y}) = BLACK" . PHP_EOL;
            }

            // I knew it's pointless but I am already desperated
            $x = intval($x);
            $y = intval($y);

            imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "</pre>";

    return $img;
}
```

Method is quite simple. Using protected variable `$this->matrix` fill image with black/lightgrey color.

Let me explain the loop - if `$this->matrix[$y][$x]` is greater than zero put black pixel, otherwise do nothing (leave light grey)

I done some debug tests, here are the results:

http://pastebin.com/8DgytNzN - Image should be all black, instead - I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4iVP.png)

Do I miss something? What is happening there?

This is how I test the method:

```
$image = $layer->getMatrixImage() ;
$fpath = "download/tmp/" . uniqid() . ".jpg";
imagejpeg($image, $fpath);
imagedestroy($image);            

echo '<img src="'.$fpath.'" /><br/>';
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the calls to `imagecollorallocate` look suspicious because there are too many of them and there is nothing else going on that may be a problem. Did you check what `imagecolorallocate` returns each time? Do the allocation once outside the loops and reuse the return value.

Comment: Strengthening my suspicion: your debug image has exactly 127 black pixels. That's not just "any" number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587802/imagesetpixel-not-working-properly-gd-lib-broken#comment27353413_18587802) I took

```
imagecolorallocate($img, 0,0,0)
```

outside my loop and everything works great